# Excel - Data Validation list from filtered table

Tags: excel, validation

I am looking for a way to make a data validation list pull from a filtered table. 
Ex. I have a sheet called customers with a table named CustomerList
column A=Customer B=Address C=City D=State
On another sheet named Quote I have cell C13 for customer name which has a data validation list to a dynamic range of Sheet Customers column A Customer. In my list it shows all 1800 customers even if i filter the table to show only customers in a certain state. I would like to be able to set filters on the table to sort my customers and have my data validation list only show the customers shown on the filtered list. For the life of me I can not figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: When we make the **DV**, should duplicated values be removed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sheet *Customers*, pick some cell and enter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,A:A)
```

This formula will be re-calculated every time the filter is changed for column **A**.

In the *Customers* worksheet code area, install the following event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Call makeDV
End Sub
```

In a standard module, install the following code:

```
Public DVList As String

Public Sub makeDV()

    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Dim c As Collection, v As Variant
    Set c = New Collection
    Set A = Intersect(Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    DVList = ""

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each r In A
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
           c.Add v, CStr(v)
           If Err.Number = 0 Then
               DVList = DVList & "," & v
           Else
            Err.Clear
           End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Len(DVList) <> 0 Then DVList = Mid(DVList, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim Quote As Worksheet
    Set Quote = Sheets("Quote")

    With Quote.Range("C13").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=DVList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Whenever the filter is modified on sheet *Customers,* the data validation for cell **C13** on sheet *Quotes* will up updated.

Comment: this sort of works. when i have a customer name that has a comma in it say Badger Pressure Control, LLC in my drop down it shows as individual entries. Badger Pressure Controls and LLC as seperate entries. Also when i sort by texas its stopping the list in the M's for some reason. Think its something to do with the way the customer may be named

Comment: When filtering by TX it stops in my list at Mountain Supply when in the customer list it is mountain supply service, not sure why though. i removed that entry and it stops on the next one. when sorted by texas i have a count of 640 in that cell and the data validation list seems to be stopping at a count of 348 if that helps. although when i have no filters it shows all 1800 customers

Comment: if i have no filters it gives me error when i clear the filters and whole table is displayed ` .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=DVList`

Comment: in debug mode when hovering about it xlValidateList=3 xlValidAlertStop=1 xlBetween=1 if that helps at all

Comment: @JasonAdams  **You have uncovered a real bug.**  The items in a *comma-separated-list* cannot contain commas themselves.  We need to use a **helper column** instead.....are you O.K. with using a helper column??

Comment: i have no clue what a helper column is. I deleted all the commas out of my customers name so thats not really an issue on listing them but i am having issues with it not listing all the customers name from my filtered list. when i went to say the file it said i needed to use binary workbook as formula was over 8000 something characters long. I changed the workbook type but i believe that the way its creating the DV List is making a string of too many characters and thats why its not listing all the customers.  (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49372768/Quote%20Template-new.xlsb)

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There may be a fundamental limit to the string approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i can still use the code you gave me just on a narrower scale than the amount of clients my company has. I will just have them deal with filtering it down to a usable list.

Comment: @JasonAdams  You have made me aware of a fundamental problem with implementing *AutoFilter* with VBA.............I will have to ivestigate!