# Excel VBA Four for each loops with dependent dropdowns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, validation, foreach

I have already posted about a similar subject at [For each loop with data validation lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170356/for-each-loop-with-data-validation-lists)

I am using data validation for two drop downs and then I am using data validation with =INDEX('2. Sheet2'!$G$2:$AC$50;;MATCH($G$3;'2. Sheet2'!$G$1:$AC$1;0)) for my two dependent drop downs.

I have tried named ranges for my dropdowns w/o success.

I am unable to get a for each loop to loop through all possible combinations of dropdown1, dropdown2 vs. dropdown3, dropdown4.

I have tried all the code in the earlier thread and I am unable to tweak it myself and I have spent a lot of time trying without success.  I am learning VBA but I still have very much to learn.

I have tried tweaking the code to:

```
Sub CostModelOutput()
    Dim dvCell As Range, dvCell2 As Range, dvCell3 As Range, dvCell4 As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range, inputRange2 As Range, inputRange3 As Range, inputRange4 As Range
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, f As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim NumberRows As Long, NumberRows2 As Long


     'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("J28")
    Set dvCell2 = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("N28")
    Set dvCell3 = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("N28")
    Set dvCell4 = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("N28")

     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("J28").Validation.Formula1)
    Set inputRange2 = Evaluate(Range("N28").Validation.Formula1)
    Set inputRange3 = Evaluate(Range("R28").Validation.Formula1)
    Set inputRange4 = Evaluate(Range("U28").Validation.Formula1)

    i = 3
    'Begin our loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Sheets("Contacts").Activate

    For Each c In inputRange
        For Each d In inputRange2
            For Each e In inputRange3
                For Each f In inputRange4

                    dvCell = c.Value
                    dvCell2 = d.Value
                    dvCell3 = e.Value
                    dvCell4 = f.Value
                    'MsgBox dvCell
                   ' MsgBox dvCell2
                   ' MsgBox dvCell3
                    'MsgBox dvCell4

                    Debug.Print dvCell, dvCell2, dvCell3, dvCell4
                                    Debug.Print dvCell, dvCell2, dvCell3, dvCell4
                    i = i + 1


            Next e
            j = j + 1
         Next d
       k = k + 1
       Next f
    l = l + 1
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For each loop with data validation lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170356/for-each-loop-with-data-validation-lists)

Comment: You already asked a very similar question there ^ Just tweak the solution *(which you by the way haven't even marked nor upvoted)*

Comment: You are correct and I added a link to the thread I posted in earlier.

Comment: This code somewhat works but it crashes excel 2016 everytime. Is there any other way to calculate a lot of different cases from four dropdowns?